# Entity Framework connection string storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, passwords, connection-string

In my DB-first system I have created a partial class that has an overloaded constructor that generates the connection string on each request.

Here is a simplified version of my code, I have reduced the connection string for simplicity:

```
    public GenericDatabase() : base(GetConnectionString())
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the connection string used to connect to the db
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return string.Format(
            "connection string=\"data source={0};initial catalog={1};persist security info=True;user id={2};password={3};",
            GetServerName(), "MyDb", GetUsername(), GetPassword());
    }
```

As you can see I retrieve the username, password and server name from elsewhere (actually an external source). Ideally I don't want to do this on EVERY database request but I'm not sure what the best way to do it is.

Should I create the connection string the first time and then store it? Should I store the parts of the string separately and then build the string every time? Or for security reasons is the current way the most ideal?

Basically, I'm just looking for the best way to build the connection string in code!

Comment: I would check out the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) which is intended for this exact purpose - building connection strings from pieces of information and making sure they are valid and properly formed ...

Comment: @marc_s Okay, but even if I use this to build the string. Should I be building it on every single request?

Comment: As long as the connection string per se stays the same: no, no point in doing so. Build it **once** at the beginning of your app and store it for later use (just the connection **string** - the actual connection should be created/opened before each request and closed right after executing the request). You could e.g. put it into ASP.NET cache under a given key (`YourApp_ConnectionString`) and make it available to all your code

Comment: Okay thanks, however ASP.NET cache is new to me? What's the benefit of using this instead of in a static property?